# How to produce HTML with non-ascii character from pyInstaller

Tags: python, html, fonts, jinja2, pyinstaller

I am building a script that should produce HTML files that include non-ascii (Hebrew) characters. The script should be wrapped as exe file (using pyInstaller).

I am using Jinja2 to create the html template, but I can not get it to read the font from inside pyInstaller wrap - I only get gibberisg characters.

The project tree looks something like:

```
root
|
--fonts
|
--src
   |
   -- main.py
```

and I use `--add-data` flag to add the font file to the executable.

Last thing I tried was:

```
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template('''
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl" >
<head lang="he">
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
        font-family: arial;
        src: src(%s);
    }
</style>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title text-align=center >{{ title }}</title>
</head>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">{{ title }}</h1>
    <body lang=he text-align=right'>
        {{ table }}
    </body>
</html>
''' % PATH_TO_FONT)
html_string = template.render(template_vars)
# Saving to HTML file
```